# DI, constructor, and field initialization execution order

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, dependency-injection, es6-class

I have the following example code in Angular:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {

    constructor(private dependentService: DependentService) {} // this is called second
    public myField$ = this.init() // this is called first

    init(){
        return this.dependentService.getAnObservable()
    }
}
```

When **MyService**  is instantiated:

- **myField$** gets initialized first before **constructor** is called. I can verify that by using e.g **console.log**
- However, **myField$** initialization relies on **dependentService**, which is injected via, again, the **constructor**

So how is that possible without any error?

Comment: Just assign `myField$` in the ctor(?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at how your example compiles to javascript - I've imported it into playground for you [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4BFhmAOwBMCYBlYKANwEsFg4BvAKDjjAFcAjJWuAc2AwAgvgDynNBUopuwABQBKAFxwU%20AJ6MWcAL5M9TUJFiJUGOAFl15KrXrNtrBBHxoYUdghjQ5YKNWkYemI8IhIbGjoVHFDifDIpOwUtVlTEFzQIJGAAOiQIPjkAImp8fAp013dPbyg4TghCdSKFAG5HXSYOjm5eAFt1ADFqYCRCABI4AF44GAALajQc0uoYRTgAeg3ZhcxFxBQkbMI4ADNqKDcutJW1hWY0tKhBdih8HcWckII4hNs6HICYRiCRSGTZRTtNJ6HRAA).

As you can see, first the fields from the constructor parameters are assigned, then the fields from outside of constructor are initialized, and only then the constructor body is executed.